# Whats the best way to create a view like this in android so that it supports various screen resolutions?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, android-framelayout

I want to label different images and all the labels must be clickable.Is their a way to add particular hotspots in imageview that respond differently?
Please guide me in right direction.

[image]

Comment: i recently came across constraint layout which allows you to set position of children based on percentage. or you can use on touch listener to get x and y and make your logic accordingly

Comment: your bitmap could be link with a JSON some things like this : {
          "content": "Lorem ",
          "x": 1000,
          "y": 74,
          "arrowOrientation": 3,
          "arrowLength": 100
        }

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own view which draws a bitmap and some lines with texts. if clicked get the position. resolve which text has been clicked.

[https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html](http://Just%20create%20your%20own%20view%20which%20draws%20a%20bitmap%20and%20some%20lines%20with%20texts.%20if%20clicked%20get%20the%20position.%20resolve%20which%20text%20has%20been%20clicked.)